Android Highchart 11.4.8 upgrade issue
I am trying to update the highcharts to the latest Android version 11.4.8. But getting the following exceptions and it's printed in the logcat. The existing chart is also not rendering after upgrade.
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined.
Expecting help from the publisher

Make sure that you have correctly included the latest version of Highcharts in your project. Sometimes, an incomplete or corrupted file can lead to these errors. Also it's worth clearing cache, as sometimes, browsers cache old versions of scripts. Clear your browser cache or test in incognito mode.
